# Функции trunc, frac, round в Java

Tags: delphi, java

В делфи есть функции `trunc, frac, round` и тп. А на Java есть соответствующие аналоги?
В особенности интересует `Frac`.

Comment: java.lang.Math, javadoc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.math.*;

double b = 3.1415926;

trunc (целая часть числа) - int a = (int)b;
fruc (дробная часть числа) - double a = ((int)b) - b;
round (округление) - int a = Math.round(b);
```

Как-то так...

Comment: fruc (дробная часть числа) - double a = ((int)b) - b;

видимо b - ((int)b) ?

Comment: ой, ну да. На самом деле даже:

double a = Math.abs(b) - ((int)b);

Answer (score 0):

Помимо самописных вариантов, могу также порекомендовать математические функции из [**Apache Commons,**](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html) а также стандартные вариации этих методов, которые опираются на использование `BigDecimal` и метода `setScale`.

*В случае, если эти функции используются не в вычислениях, а предполагают использование, например, при выводе на экран, то можно ограничиться использованием `DecimalFormat.`*

Более подробно можно посмотреть [**тут.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976809/are-there-any-functions-for-truncating-a-double-in-java)